# Setting attributes on a method after class creation raises "'instancemethod' object has no attribute" but the attribiute is clearly there

Tags: python, methods, first-class-functions

In Python (2 and 3) we can assign attributes to function:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         """ This is obviously just an example """
...         return "FOO{}!!".format(self.foo.bar)
...     foo.bar = 123
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo()
'FOO123!!'
```

And that's cool.

But why cannot we change `foo.bar` at a later time? For example, in the constructor, like so:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...         print(self.foo.bar)
...         self.foo.bar = 456  # KABOOM!
...     def foo(self):
...         """ This is obviously just an example """
...         return "FOO{}!!".format(self.foo.bar)
...     foo.bar = 123
...
>>> a = A()
123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Python claims there is no `bar` even though it printed it fine on just the previous line.

Same error happens if we try to change it directly on the class:

```
>>> A.foo.bar
123
>>> A.foo.bar = 345  # KABOOM!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

What's happening here, i.e. why are we seeing this behaviour?

Is there a way to set attributes on a function after class creation?

(I'm aware of multiple alternatives, but I'm explicitly wondering about attributes on methods here, or possibly a broader issue.)

---

Motivation: Django makes use of the possibility to set attributes on methods, e.g:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def custom_admin_column(self, obj):
        return obj.something()
    custom_admin_column.admin_order_field ='relation__field__span'
    custom_admin_column.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: `self.foo` isn't the `foo` function you defined. Among other distinguishing features, `self.foo` takes zero arguments, while the `foo` function you wrote takes one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `foo.bar` inside the class body works because `foo` is the actual `foo` function. However, when you do

```
self.foo.bar = 456
```

`self.foo` isn't that function. `self.foo` is an *instance method object*, created on demand when you access it. You can't set attributes on it for several reasons:

1. If those attributes are stored on the `foo` function, then assigning to `a.foo.bar` has an unexpected effect on `b.foo.bar`, contrary to all the usual expectations about attribute assignment.
2. If those attributes are stored on the `self.foo` instance method object, they won't show up the next time you access `self.foo`, because you'll get a new instance method object next time.
3. If those attributes are stored on the `self.foo` instance method object and you change the rules so `self.foo` is always the same object, then that massively bloats every object in Python to store a bunch of instance method objects you almost never need.
4. If those attributes are stored in `self.__dict__`, what about objects that don't have a `__dict__`? Also, you'd need to come up with some sort of name mangling rule, or store non-string keys in `self.__dict__`, both of which have their own problems.

If you want to set attributes on the `foo` function after the class definition is done, you can do that with `A.__dict__['foo'].bar = 456`. (I've used `A.__dict__` to bypass the issue of whether `A.foo` is the function or an unbound method object, which depends on your Python version. If `A` inherits `foo`, you'll have to either deal with that issue or access the dict of the class it inherits `foo` from.)